# Migrate Junit4 to Junit5 test cases

Tags: junit, junit5

I have this JUnit4 test which I would like to migrate to JUnit5:

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs.class)
public class TasksTest {

  @Test(expected = Exception.class)
  public void createTaskTest() {
    .....
  }
}
```

What should be proper wya to migrate this?

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs.class)
public class TasksTest {

  @Test(expected = Exception.class)
  public void createTaskTest() {
    .....
  }
}
```

But I get these errors: `Incompatible types. Found: 'java.lang.Class<org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner.StrictStubs>', required: 'java.lang.Class<? extends org.junit.jupiter.api.extension`

and

```
Cannot resolve method 'expected'
```

Can you advise how this can be fixed?

Comment: What kind of research, e.g. plain web searches, have you already done? There’s a lot of stuff out there about migrating JUnit 4 to 5. Have you looked at that?

Comment: Here is an article https://www.baeldung.com/junit-5-migration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Migration tips](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/#migrating-from-junit4-tips) from JUnit guide suggest to use `Assertions.assertThrows`:

```
@Test
public void createTaskTest() throws Exception {
    Assertions.assertThrows(Exception.class, () -> {
        //.....
    });
}
```

Regarding "Migrate" refactoring in IDEA, there's a ticket to support `expected` and `timeout`: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-230146, you can vote for it